# Chrome sizing bug or my misunderstanding?

Tags: css, google-chrome

When I view the following in Chrome 13.0.782.215 Linux, I find that the div is 5px too high.  Looking in the inspector, it seems that chrome is calculating the height of the contents to be 37px (30 + 5 + 2*1 for the borders).  Is the 5px a bug?  I don't see this problem in Firefox 3.6 or 6.0.

http://jsfiddle.net/drpXE/5/

Comment: I'm also seeing it in windows 7 from the link you provided. I had noticed this before on a task I was working on, never knew what caused it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/drpXE/12/

In this case it's not extra padding, it's merely the textarea position with inline text. Set it vertical-align to something like text-top, or middle and you will see the extra 5px disappear.

```
textarea
{
    height:30px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

It all depends on whatever else you add to the div and how you want it to look.

Comment: It appears that changing vertical-align to anything other than baseline resolves the problem, so this does appear to be a chrome bug.